# Is Twilio enough for International SMS verification?

Tags: android, ios, sms, twilio, sms-gateway

I used Twilio to send SMS verification in my app. I just send a single SMS per user using the Twilio REST API.

However, after launching, we got several complaints from international users. They never got the SMS.

What is the best way to implement SMS/Voice verification that works almost everywhere?

And yes, International SMS is enabled in my Twilio Account.

```
def sendByTwilio(phone, verificationCode):
try:
    account_sid = "XXXXX"
    auth_token = "XXXXXX"
    client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
    rv = client.sms.messages.create(to="phone",
                                    from_="XXXXXXXXXX",
                                    body="Your verification code is "+str(verificationCode))
    return True
except TwilioRestException, e:
    pass

return False
```

Comment: I would NOT recommend Twilio. There docs say they support international SMS, but after talking to their tech reps it appears it does in fact, NOT work. Such a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why the SMS might not be working in international locations. Twilio works good on some places but not everywhere. In India they are very limited and would not recommend using them - https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices.

I don't think that the API version would change the deliverability of the SMS, when you go international the hurdles of making sure the SMS is received goes beyond the SMS Gateway. Read this for more info on improving SMS reception globally [check out this](http://blog.ringcaptcha.com/issues-implementing-sms-verification/).

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Kamran is right, you should check your international permissions in your account.

One other thing is that you are using the [SMS/Messages resource which has been deprecated](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms). If you update your code to:

```
rv = client.messages.create(to="phone",
                            from_="XXXXXXXXXX",
                            body="Your verification code is "+str(verificationCode))
```

then you will use the newer [Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) resource.

Comment: I agree with philnash about the sms api deprecation. Though i have used C# version of sms messaging but got multiple problems.So i used the other messaging api which works quite fine other then one problem that when message is reached to client the number is randomly generated one instead of the number we buy from twilio

Comment: @KamranShahid if you're having that problem, then please raise it (if you haven't already) with Twilio support at help@twilio.com.

Comment: Ok phil.Just letting alienprogrammer knows what problem he might also face as he is messaging some verification code and if customer reply to possible randomly generated number then reply might not reach.

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: @GN. What issue are you having? [edit] Never mind, found your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the geographical location? If no you have to enabled it from twilio account settings. Secondary you should do some logging for TwilioException .May be number might not be prefixed with + sign which causes problems